# Arranging 4 Piles into 5 Piles - Pigeonhole Principle [Continued]

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I read the following exercise in my combinatorics book in the section on the Pigeonhole Principle.

> There are four heaps of stones in our backyard. We rearrange them
>   into five heaps. Prove that at least two stones are placed into a smaller
>   heap.

and this is the proof that I read:

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding the intuition and reasonining/logic in this proof, mainly after the $a_k > b_k$ step. I'm having difficulty seeing why we need the following inequality and how the conclusion follows from it.

I would appreciate any explanation or elaboration on this proof in helping to understand.

Comment: Apparently it is assumed a "heap" (or pile, if you prefer) cannot be empty.  Otherwise we could put all stones (if any!) in the original four heaps into a single combined heap and count four additional *empty* heaps as giving a total of five heaps.  In this way no stone would be placed into a heap smaller than the one it original appeared in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, it took me several minutes to even understand what they meant by 'at least two stones are placed into a smaller heap', because I pictured just moving 1 stone from the 4 old heaps and creating, all by itself, a fifth heap, so I figured as such we would only be placing 1 stone into a smaller heap.

But I think I understand: when I move the 1 stone, then all the other stones remaining in the old heap where I took the 1 stone from are now in a heap that is 1 smaller than it was and, as such, they are also 'placed into a smaller heap'. Which means there are indeed two or more.

So, what they mean is: if you have 4 heaps of stones, and make those into 5 heaps of stones, then there will be at least two stones that end up in a heap that is smaller than the size of the heap that they were in.

Now, as far as their argument goes: we have of course that $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5$, with each of these $\ge 1$, and so indeed $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4>b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4$. Now, it could be that $b_1>a_1$, or that $b_2>a_2$, or that $b_4>a_4$, but it has to be the case that there is a smallest $k$ for which $a_1+...+a_k>b_1+...b_k$. And since this is the smallest $k$, it has to be the case that $a_k>b_k$, for if $a_k \le b_k$, then $a_1...a_{k-1}>b_1...b_{k-1}$, and hence $k$ would not have been the smallest index to get our inequality.

Now, consider all the stones in piles $a_1$ through $a_k$. In order for them to not end up in smaller heaps, they need to be put into piles $b_1$ through $b_{k-1}$, since al these piles are bigger than $b_k$. But that leaves $a_1+...+a_k-b_1-...-b_{k-1} > b_k$ stones, and since $b_k \ge 1$, that means that at least two stones cannot be put in piles $b_1$ through $b_{k-1}$, so at least two stones from the piles $a_1$ through $a_k$ must have ended up in piles of size $b_k$ or smaller, thus proving the claim.